# Cloudflare with WPRocket

Tags: wordpress, cdn, cloudflare

So... I just created a new CDN through CF. I'd like to know how long does it take the DNS to propagate worldwide? I tried registering the CDN that I created in CF into WPRocket but it's breaking my site. I don't know if is because of the timeframe that I need to wait or that I'm doing something wrong within the crypto config in CF.

Answer (score 1):

Generally cloudflare takes 24 hours to propogate dns records through wordwide. After that website will serve request through cloudflare. And issue of your site brokedown is may be minification of jQuery or css in wp-rocket or defer parsing of script. Also you can use http://whatsmydns.net  for checking DNS entries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure the CDN section in WP Rocket for services like cloudflare or sucuri.

There's an addon (activated inside WP Rocket) for cloudflare where you just need to fill in your API key and that's it.

I believe you don't even need to set the addon and the API key for cloudflare to work with your website and WP Rocket, the addon is "just" for controling cloudflare directly from wordpress dashboard (purge cloudflare cache, enable development mode, etc)